# Simple search form passing the searched string through GET

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like my Search form to return the following url after submit:

> /anuncios/buscar/the_text_I_searched

My form is the following:

```
<% form_for :announcement, :url => search_path(:txtSearch) do |f| %>
<div class="searchBox" id="basic">
  <%= text_field_tag :txtSearch, params[:str_search].blank? ? "Busc&aacute; tu curso r&aacute;pido y f&aacute;cil." : params[:str_search], :maxlength=> 100, :class => "basicSearch_inputField", :onfocus => "if (this.value=='Busc&aacute; tu curso r&aacute;pido y f&aacute;cil.') this.value=''", :onblur => "if(this.value=='') { this.value='Busc&aacute; tu curso r&aacute;pido y f&aacute;cil.'; return false; }" %>
  <div class="basicSearch_button">
    <input type="submit" value="BUSCAR" class="basicSearch_buttonButton" />
    <br /><a href="#" onclick="javascript:jQuery('#advance').modal({opacity:60});">Busqueda avanzada</a>
  </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

My routes' line for search_path is this:

```
map.search '/anuncios/buscar/:str_search', :controller => 'announcements', :action => 'search'
```

Well, this will work if I manually type the url I want in the brower, but definitely, if you look at the form's url, you'll find a ":txtSearch" parameter, which is not giving me the actual value of the text field when the form is submitted. And that's what I'd like to get!

Could anybody help me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this in the controller:

```
def search
  ...
  redirect_to search_path(:str_search => params[:txtSearch])
end
```

Comment: This works. Now I've got a question...I noticed that if the querystring param is null, let's say I type "/anuncios/buscar" (without any string to search) it will raise an error because it cannot find the action to execute. What can I do to catch this action?(I'd like to show all the announcements if no string to search is specified in the url).

Comment: Check `params[:txtSearch].blank?` and render the page containing the search form if it is, otherwise do the redirect.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you'll need to submit the form to another action, format the search string, and then redirect_to your search page using the new search string.