# rails form_for and route with nested param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, routes

Don't really know how to look for this, so without a long search I post this here.

What I want is a url like this:

```
/domains/whois/domainname.com
```

The problem is when I use a form the params get in the url like this:

```
/domains/whois/?utf8=✓&whois%5Bdomain%5D=domainname.com&commit=submit
```

My routes are like this at the moment:

```
namespace :domains do

    match "whois(/:domain)" => "whois#index"

end
```

My form is like this:

```
<%= form_for :whois, :method => :get do |form| %>
    <%= form.text_field :domain %>
    <%= form.submit "Vertel" %>
<% end %>
```

Anybody knows what I should do to get the param nested in the route?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer here:
[Simple search form passing the searched string through GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045970/simple-search-form-passing-the-searched-string-through-get)

Guess it's not possible without the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using post instead of get for forms.

This means all the forms will be posted in the body of the http request and you get to keep you're pretty url like /domains/whois/domainname.com